# Flutter ontap works in simulator but not consistent in mobile

Tags: flutter, random

I have flutter ontap guesture that works well in simulator but does not work consistently on mobile when installed.

On simulator it works always but on mobile randomly works dont know how to debug.

Comment: It may sound silly, but maybe the tappable area is quite small and you miss it with your finger from time to time. I had similar issues at the past, my workaround was to make the area bigger by wrapping it in a larger `Container` with `transparent` color.

Comment: can you add code snippet